# Creating deep copy of a pre-trained model for finetuning in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, deep-copy, pre-trained-model, vgg-net, fine-tuning

I am trying to make a deep copy of a VGG-19 model. I want to use the original pre-trained model for feature extraction of images and also fine tune another version of the model by creating a deep copy of it. But for some reason, when I set requires.grad = False for the original model, it gets reflected in the copied model as well. I am assuming the deep copy is not working as expected here.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import copy
vgg = model.vgg
vgg.load_state_dict(torch.load(args.vgg))
Encoder = copy.deepcopy(vgg)
Encoder.train()
Encoder.to(device)
optimizer_E = torch.optim.Adam(Encoder.parameters(), lr=args.e_lr)
```

Any idea on why it isn't working?

I want to extract content and style features separately. So for the fixed model I have set:

```
vgg = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg.children())[:31])
#Inside the class
 feature_extractor  = list(vgg.children())
 self.layer_1 = nn.Sequential(*feature_extractor[:4])  
 self.layer_2 = nn.Sequential(*feature_extractor[4:11])  
 self.layer_3 = nn.Sequential(*feature_extractor[11:18])  
 self.layer_4 = nn.Sequential(*feature_extractor[18:31])  
 # fix the encoder 
 for name in ['layer_1', 'layer_2', 'layer_3', 'layer_4']:
     for param in getattr(self, name).parameters():
         param.requires_grad = False
```

For the Encoder, I have done the same except for setting `param.requires_grad = True`

Comment: Deepcopying pytorch models should work fine the way you did it. Hence the issue should be somewhere else. Can you give a minimal code example of your issue, including how you set the `requires.grad`?

Comment: @RobinvanHoorn I have edited my question. Kindly have a look.